# How to delete content of sheetnode spreadsheet field?

Tags: 7, entities

I am using the [Sheetnode](https://www.drupal.org/project/sheetnode) spreadsheet module to upload data. I am looking for ideas on how to clear the contents of the spreadsheet each time the form is loaded.

I have tried setting form state using all the following ways:

```
hottopicsresearchsheet_form_hottopics_node_form_alter() {
  $node = $form_state['node'];
  $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  unset($node->field_spreadsheet[$node->language][0]);
  $form['#node']->field_spreadsheet[$node->language][0]['value'] = "";
  $node_wrapper->field_spreadsheet->set(NULL);
}

function hottopicsresearchsheet_field_widget_sheetfield_spreadsheet_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  $element['#entity']->field_spreadsheet['und']['0']['value'] = "";
  $form_state['field']['field_spreadsheet'] = array('name' => '', 'value' => '');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I found was to not save the data in the first place. Will make debugging harder, but here it is:

```
function hottopicsresearchsheet_node_presave($node) {
  // Check that the nodes of the type I need and process data...

  // Clear data.
  if (!empty($node->field_spreadsheet[$node->language][0]['value'])) {
    unset($node->field_spreadsheet[$node->language]);
  }
}
```